# Bias in Gradient Descent (GD) and Stochastic GD (SGD)

Tags: optimization, expected-value, gradient-descent

Let $\theta$ be weight parameters and assume the loss function to be $L_N(\theta)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_i f(\theta; x_i,y_i)$. Assume a mini batch loss function with a batch of size $M$ and denote the loss as $L_M(\theta)$. One can directly show that

1. $E(L_M(\theta))=E(L_N(\theta))$ if all data $(x_i,y_i)$ are iid.
2. Now assume we do one step of GD for $L_N(\theta)$ - $\Big[\theta^N_1=\theta_0-\frac{\alpha_0}{N}f^{\prime}(\theta; x_i,y_i) \Big]$ and 1 step of GD for $L_M(\theta)$ - $\Big[\theta^M_1=\theta_0-\frac{\alpha_0}{M}f^{\prime}(\theta; x_i,y_i)\Big]$. Clearly, $E(\theta^N_1)=E(\theta^M_1)$.

However is $E(L_N(\theta^N_1))=E(L_M(\theta^M_1))$ ? Here there are two layers of stochasticity one in  $\theta^{N\,\mbox{or}\,M}_1$ and $L_{N\,\mbox{or}\,M}$

Comment: the loss are evaluated in the same mini-batch, or in a second one?

Comment: @carlo $L_N$ uses the full data while $L_M$ uses a batch size $M$.

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to give an analytical answer in the general case, the distribution of X and y and the loss function should be provided. I suspect that the expected loss of the mini-batch may be lower in most usual cases, because overfitting is easier with less data.